# How can i upload/download files to/from a remote server through my website in php?

Tags: php

Actually, i have opened a site in a free web hosting company which is not offering file sharing facility (i.e. to store files in different formats) so online chat community of d same site advised me to store the files in a remote server of sites such as rapidshare.com, mediafire.com. But i need downloading and uploading facilities in my website. So i have decided to run uploading and downloading php scripts frm my website which will be connected to the remote server, but i'm afraid scripts are not working. As my user name in mediafire is "karthik_raju1@yahoo.com" when executing the code with this user name i have got an "Error:username must not contain '@' symbol". Can u please suggest me d code to upload files to remote server and kindly suggest me some important tips ,if any...

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you should find a new free host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to store other files, a simple solution would be to consider a better free host such as 000webhost.com or byethost.com or awardspace (This is not an advertisement).

Comment: i have hosted my website in byethost. in its Terms and Conditions it has been mentioned dat no rar,doc,e.t.c file formats are allowed. are u sure dat dey r also providing free file sharing facilities???

Comment: Then try 000webhost. They are really flexible and have great limits.